# Syntax error on token ")", ; expected after this token while expression

Tags: java

So I'm creating a program using JOptionPane and using do while. I only have 1 error which is

> Syntax error on token ")", ; expected after this token while
>   expression on "while (select > 5)

Here's my code

```
public class Labwork2ABUEL {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    float num;
    String choice, input, numInput;
    int select, area, width, height, n, i, f;

    double radius, area1;


    Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};

    do {
        choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Main Menu " +
    "\n 1. COMPUTE FOR AN AREA OF CIRCLE"
    + "\n 2. COMPUTE FOR AN AREA OF SQUARE"
    + " \n 3. COMPUTE FOR AN AREA OF RECTANGLE"
    + "\n 4. COMPUTE FOR A FACTORIAL OF A NUMBER"
    + "\n 5. EXIT THE PROGRAM");
    }

    while (select > 5)
    {   
        choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter only 1-5!" +
    "\n Main Menu +"
    + "\n 1. COMPUTE FOR AN AREA OF CIRCLE"
    + "\n 2. COMPUTE FOR AN AREA OF SQUARE"
    + "\n 3. COMPUTE FOR AN AREA OF RECTANGLE"
    + "\n 4. COMPUTE FOR A FACTORIAL OF A NUMBER"
    + "\n 5. EXIT THE PROGRAM");
    }

    if (select == 1)
    {
        choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Radius", "Circle Area Input");
        radius = Double.parseDouble(input);
        area1 = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        String message = "Area of Circle: " + area1;
        String title = "Circle Area Output";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, title, select);
```

Comment: it's `do { ... }while(condition);`, not `do { ... } while(condition) { ... }`

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG Actually I already tried that and didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `while (some condition);` after the closing `}` of the `do` loop.

Or, you are missing a `;` after `while (select > 5)`.

But after that, you're going to get a whole shedload of errors relating to uninitialized variables, like `select`. And a load of logical errors, like not changing `select` in the `while (select > 5)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
        choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Main Menu " +
    "\n 1. COMPUTE FOR AN AREA OF CIRCLE"
    + "\n 2. COMPUTE FOR AN AREA OF SQUARE"
    + " \n 3. COMPUTE FOR AN AREA OF RECTANGLE"
    + "\n 4. COMPUTE FOR A FACTORIAL OF A NUMBER"
    + "\n 5. EXIT THE PROGRAM");
    }while(some condition);//missing it.
```